# Set Featured Image by URL Form Post

Tags: post-thumbnails

How do I append a form URL to set as my featured image?

I am working on a user frontend submission site that is pretty basic and using WP User Frontend Plugin.

I finally figured out the GIF URL preview by creating an html widget within the plugin and using the  `$('.preview-image').attr('src', inputVal).fadeIn();`
jQuery. Everything works and will create a new post.

My problem I'm running into, is I need to reference the "GIF URL" as the Featured Image in order for the Post to show on the page. I am referencing the Featured Image via Elementor.

http://jsfiddle.net/dafitime/u9yk8L5b/7/